# Как добавить возможность просмотра большого графика matplotlib через ползунок

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Помогите советом начинающему программисту. Разрабатываю программу для анализа данных. Требуется построить график зависимости изменения величины во времени (ось Х - колонка DataFrame pandas типа datetime). Обрабатываемые данные довольно массивные - порядка 1,2 - 1,5 млн строк, из-за чего matplotlib сжимает сильно график и его анализ становится проблематичен. Хотелось бы предусмотреть возможность добавления скроллбара для перемотки графика "туда-сюда" (ось Х datetime) и его дальнейшего анализа. Почитав форум, добавил по примеру Slider Widget из библиотеки matplotlib, но при перемотке ползунка вперед, а затем назад рисуется пустой график и ось Х начинает принимать рандомные значения, вместо указанных в DataFrame (проще говоря, график мотается ползунком только вперед, а при возвращении назад все сбивается). Прикладываю код ниже. Грешу на то, что при создании объекта Slider нужно указывать значения формата datetime, на которые он будет ссылаться при перемещении ползунка. Не понимаю, как можно это указать. Отметил эти строки в коде. Надеюсь, все изложил доступно. Спасибо!

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\doc.txt', sep = ',')
df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], format = '%Y%m%d %H%M%S%f')
print(df)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.25)
plt.plot(df.DATETIME, df.VALUE, 's-r')
plt.axis()
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03]) # данные значения не изменял
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Position', 1, 90.0, dragging = True) # и эти тоже
def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.axis([pos, pos+10, 0, 1]) #ну и эти :D
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    spos.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950690/matplotlib-more-efficient-way-to-update-chart-when-using-slider-to-scroll-throug в принятом ответе готовое рабочее решение.